# AviSynth AvsP disolve not working

Tags: avisynth

I'm trying to make a 30sec video of images and can't seem to find useful information on how to achieve this if someone could point me to some examples would be great, other then that I got my script below I think dissolve should connect images is that right? What about how to connect first message window and make it appear first? Basically all three of these I want to go from to bottom as a video clip.

Script below:

```
MyMessage="Wireless Communications"
MessageClip(MyMessage, 320,240, text_color=color_antiquewhite, 
\bg_color=color_blue)

Rails="C:\Users\me\Desktop\1.png"
RailClip=ImageReader(Rails,start=0,end=100,fps=25)
Info(RailClip)

PointResize(RailClip, 320,240, 0,20, 148,148)

Rails2="C:\Users\me\Desktop\3.jpg"
RailClip2=ImageReader(Rails2,start=101,end=200,fps=25)

Dissolve(RailClip+RailClip2,25)
```

error: 'frame sizes don't match'.

Comment: Is `3.jpg` 320x240?  Also, can you clarify what you mean by "all three of these I want to go from to bottom as a video clip"?